# Ringtone picker returns null intent always

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm trying to read the value from ringtone picker, but in onactivityresult i get NULL intent.

Here is the code i use to launch the ringtone picker

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone for notifications:");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    startActivityForResult(intent,999);
```

Here i get NULL as response in onactivityresult, with response code requestCode as 100. resultcode 0

requestCode should be 999 but i get 100.

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //Data i get as NULL, it should be valid intent 
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {

        case 100:

Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

         }
}
```

Comment: did you add required permissions to manifest?

Comment: what is the permission?, i'm able to launch ringtone picker but values i'm not able to read

Comment: you have to put these three permissions to android.manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>

Comment: Yes, i have added those settings. in onactivityresult i'm not getting correct result code i.e 999 & intent i.e data is NULL

Answer (score 3):

I know this is REALLY late, but this is how it needs to be done

```
Uri pickedUri= (Uri) data.getExtras().get(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
```